# Git (GitLab) - Merge Fails - Trying instructions for "Check out, review, merge locally"

Tags: git, gitlab, merge-conflict-resolution

I tried to do a merge from my user-branch to our shared "develop" branch.  I'm the only working on this project.  GitLab gave me the following instructions which I'm struggling with.

[image]

in Step 1 - when I did "git fetch origin" - I did it in the repository I already on my hard drive.  Was that correct?  If I try it in some newly made directory, it syas "fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

for the second part of Step 1 - 
I get the error: 
fatal: A branch name 'nw-ob210refactor' already exists.

So I tried adding a 2 on the end, and I get this error: 
fatal: 'origin/nw-ob210refactor2' is not a commit and a branch 'nw-ob210refactor
' cannot be created from it

Are the above instructions form GitLab complete and correct; or am I doing some obviously wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git checkout -b localName origin/onlineName
```

creates a new local branch. See `man git checkout`

> -b "new_branch"
>   Creates the branch "new_branch" and start it at "start_point"; if it already exists, then reset it to "start_point". This is equivalent to running "git branch" with "-f"; see git-branch(1) for details

if you aleady have the according branch local ofcourse you don't want to create it again. Instead use only

```
git checkout nw-ob210refactor
```

and than

```
git pull
```

---

> If I try it in some newly made directory

there you would have to do a fresh

```
git clone https://your/repository
```

first to download your repository

> So I tried adding a 2 on the end, and I get this error: fatal: 'origin/nw-ob210refactor2' is not a commit and a branch 'nw-ob210refactor ' cannot be created from it

if something and you want to create a new local branch you have to change the parameter after `-b` (= the local brnach name) not the origin (remote branch name) you are trying to download:

```
git checkout -b checkout nw-ob210refactor2 origin/checkout nw-ob210refactor
```

---

**Update**

Once you are `Already up to date` go on with step 3

do also there either

```
git checkout -b develop origin/develop
```

if the `develop` branch does **not** exist local so far. Otherwise again use only

```
git checkout develop
```

to only switch to it. In that case to be sure again run

```
git pull
```

Now you have both branches local and up-to-date and are ready to merge

```
git merge --no-ff nw-ob210refactor
```

This merges `nw-ob210refactor` into `develop`. If you need it the otherway round simply switch to the target branch (`checkout`) and exchange the name.

`--no-ff` reads `no fast forward` and means

> Create a merge commit even when the merge resolves as a fast-forward. This is the default behaviour when merging an annotated (and possibly signed) tag that is not stored in its natural place in refs/tags/ hierarchy.

or in simple words you want to create a special commit that will have the message `merge from branch nw-ob210refactor into develop` even though there are no conflicts and you actually could merge the branches without an additional commit. This is most of time useful to have a better overview what was merged when in the history and makes it easier to revert stuff later in case you need to.

---

after merging push back the according branch you merged to. In this example it was `develop` so do

```
git push origin develop
```

Comment: Thanks, Added what I did to other similar answer.

Comment: Thanks, muddle through it with your help.  I do think GitLab gave some bad commands...

Comment: Glad to help! Well, they are not "bad" but apparently they simply assume that you have `develop` local already but `nw-ob210refactor` not

Comment: We have standard branches develop, release (QA), and master (PROD).  So now, when I merge the fixed develop branch to release, I have to the same rigmarole again, then probably again to get it to master branch.  I don't know really how I got out of sync to begin with.

Comment: Well as soon as you commit something to one branch you always have to merge this new state of art into all other branches if neccessary (so at least up). That's how this works. A good practise is to allways merge down from the master before starting development so you have atleast the latest state and are not doing some fixes again which maybe are already committed to the remote branch. Also meanwhile during development you sould from time to time merge down from the master if there was stuff going on lately to make sure your local version won't brake /collide with stuff on the master later

Answer (score 1):

Your `git fetch origin` was correct. This fetches the latest refs from a remote named `origin`. Now when you're trying to check out, it is likely that you already have a branch of that name (and it may even be on the same commit as is on the remote).

Just to make sure, you should `pull` after you switch to the branch.

```
git checkout nw-ob210refactor
git pull
```

then move on to Step 2.

---

**Note** You could create a second branch referencing this remote branch, but I don't think it's necessary. In case you were curious about how to get your "add a 2" scenario to work, you have to add it to the local branch name, not the remote branch name:

```
git checkout -b nw-ob210refactor2 origin/nw-ob210refactor
```

Comment: In existing repository, tried your "git checkout nw-ob210refactor", it said "already on 'nw-ob210refactor' Your branch is up to date with 'origin/nw-ob210refactor".  I did the "git pull" anyway, says "Already up to date".  So what next? Do I jump to Step 3 merge now? And are the GitLab instructions wrong?

Comment: Your checkout was a no-op because were already on the branch. Your pull was a no-op because you were already at the HEAD of the branch. Success. Feel free to still do Step 2, though because you were already at the appropriate revision in your tree, you likely know what the changes were in that commit. Go to Step 3.

The GitLab instructions are not wrong, they're just not complete. They work perfectly on a system that has not yet checked out that branch (i.e. someone doing a peer review). They should add a note about the original developer's instruction differences.